# Redirecionamento de porta

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, firewall

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

Alterei a porta do MySQL 54235, no servidor linux Centos, aceito conexões de fora apenas nessa porta.

Tenho um software de terceiros antigo e descontinuado, onde não existe opção para alterar a porta padrão 3306. Porém, esse software deverá acessar de 2 ips fixos externos.

Como faço para configurar no linux para aceitar conexão na porta 3306 somente desses 2 ips fixos, e internamente, redirecionar a conexão para a porta 54235?

Comment: Faz parte de programação, pois o banco de dados usado no sistema precisa da liberação específica para poder funcionar no servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Inicialmente um ponto importante, no iptables as regras de `PREROUTING` que fazem os redirecionamentos de portas executam antes das regras de filtro que definem quais portas pode ser acessadas e por quais IPs,  como pode-se ver no diagrama abaixo:

[image: diagrama de regras do iptables]

Assim, quando um IP tentar acessar a porta `3306` ele primeiramente será redirecionado para a porta `54235` e só em seguida são executadas as regras de filtragem de quais portas ele pode acessar. Isto significa dizer que qualquer IP que tenha acesso a porta `54235` conseguirá também acessar a porta `3306` mesmo que não tenha acesso a ela já que assim que ele acessar a porta `3306` ele já será redirecionado e só depois se verificará se ele pode acessar (mas agora ele já está na porta `54235`).

---

Sabendo disto, caso deseje continuar então configure o iptables da seguinte forma para permitir acesso apenas a determinado ip na porta 3306 (esta regra não será útil pois como dito anteriormente ela não será verificada apenas coloquei para deixar claro as regras do iptables):

```sh
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s IP_AQUI --dport 3306 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 3306 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

A primeira regra você deve repetir para os dois IPs permitidos, isto fará com que apenas os ips definidos nesta regra consigam iniciar uma conexão nesta porta, o segundo passo é redirecionar as portas, o comando é este:

```sh
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j REDIRECT --to-port 54235
```

Por fim para não permitir outras conexões na porta `3306` (novamente esta regra também não sera executada)

```sh
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP
```

Para aceitar todas as conexões na porta 54235

```sh
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 54235 -j ACCEPT
```

E para modificar a política padrão para DROP

```sh
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado. Irei testar e posto o resultado.

Comment: Lucas, funcionou certinho, já não sabia mais o que fazer. Grato.

Comment: Aparece que eu preciso de 15 de reputação para poder marcar :/

Comment: Outro detalhe Lucas, o redirecionamento funcionou, porém, verifiquei que outros IPs estão tendo acesso, sendo que só liberei 2 pelo primeiro comando.

Comment: Pesquisando em fóruns, adicionei esse comando para bloquear por padrão a porta 3306, mas não funcionou:
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j DROP

Comment: @power suponho que esteja dizendo que outros ips conseguem se conectar usando a porta 3306. Adicionei este detalhe a minha resposta mas resumindo aqui no iptables a regra de `PREROUTING` que faz o redirecionamento de portas é executada primeiro que as regras que fazem a filtragem de acesso, isso significa qualquer ip ao acessar a porta 3306 conseguirá acessar se também tiver acesso a porta 54235.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, então não tem como fazer um PREROUTING sem bloquear outros IPs? Existiria alguma solução alternativa que eu possa pesquisar?

Comment: Talvez algum plugin mas nisto não posso te ajudar pois não conheço.

Comment: Lucas, só mais uma coisa por favor, se puder me ajudar.
Criei um servidor na amazon, para aproveitar o filtro de ip de entrada que eles possuem. Então estou querendo agora apenas redirecionar um ip externo e porta para outro ip externo e porta. Tentei os comandos abaixo, mas sem sucesso:

sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d ip_externo_entrada --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to ip_externo_saida:porta_saida

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp --dport porta_entrada -d ip_externo_entrada -j ACCEPT

Desde já grato pela atenção.